# Two timestamp columns in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need two timestamp columns in my table for sync purposes.

One: for modification (updates on a row) is not the problem,
Second: for insert purpose

These two would allow me to differ if the record from last sync was updated or inserted.

The field for update column will be of timestamp type.

The field for insert column could be of varbinary type but don't know how to automatically enter the value when inserting new records and where to take it from?

Comment: You are talking about [`rowversion`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) I presume?

Comment: Yes about rowversion.

Comment: You can insert the `@@DBTS` value into the insert column during an insert (possibly as a default for the column) but it will give you the value of the counter from before the `INSERT` started (i.e. at the same time, the update column will receive `rowversion` values that are all higher than the value the `@@DBTS` returns). Also, all rows in a single `INSERT` would receive the *same* `@@DBTS` value.

Comment: Well I think the perfect situation would be if I could just use the value inserted into a rowversion column. To have it the same.. But without trigger or something this cannot be done?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. By the time you know the value that's assigned to the `rowversion` column, it's too late to affect the contents of any other columns in the same row. And obviously, if you attempt to take that value and update the other column with the value, it counts as an update so it changes again.